# The difference between dual loop DC analysis and normal DC analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is the difference between dual loop DC analysis and normal DC analysis ?

Is their difference dual loop DC analysis have two source,maybe DC and DC, AC and AC ,or DC and current source ;and normal DC analysis have just one source,DC voltage source?

Comment: As far as I know DC is DC, what particular simulator advertises dual loop DC?

Comment: They **sound** different, as one has the word 'dual loop' in the title, and the other has 'normal'. Provide a link to where you heard this so that we can understand the context.

Comment: For normal DC analysis ,it is just the DC analysis we saw from the books,and the 'dual loop' DC analysis ,i see it from CMOS circuit Design,Layout,and Simulation,by R.JACOB BAKER,p13 and p15

Comment: The link is here https://books.google.fr/books?id=kxYhNrOKuJQC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=dual+loop+dc+analysis&source=bl&ots=kqQUu92uXN&sig=wTRq_OKG2CHLe63UcsgkQMZRfjE&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivovLuxLDVAhUmKMAKHZurCfIQ6AEINTAB#v=onepage&q=dual%20loop%20dc%20analysis&f=false and the only thing I see is an extra voltage source biasing the collector which fixes the operating point. The author seems to calls it "dual loop dc analysis" as the operating point depends on the \$V_{cc}\$ source and \$i_b\$ unlike in the diode example where the bias point depends on a single source only. Not very common.